# Не могу понять почему ругается на код android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
fun openMe(view: View) {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.type = "image/*"
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE)
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Это компилятор сообщает вам, что не может обнаружить переменную с именем `PICK_IMAGE`. Это должно быть число, уникально идентифицирующее запуск активити выбора картинки, чтобы потом можно было понять кто вызвал `onActivityResult`. Т.е. просто создайте переменную (точнее константу) с таким именем и дайте её к-л значение. Например `42`.